# Making a text file grow by replicating on mac

Tags: linux, macos, text, command-line

I am doing some unit tests and I have a small text file (a few kilobytes) and what I would like to do is make a new file out of this where the same text is replicated over and over again for some user specified times. The reason I want to do this is to ensure that my algorithm can handle large files and the results are correct (I can extrapolate the correct results from the tests ran on the smaller text file).

Is there a utility on the mac or linux platform that allows me to do that?

Comment: `for cnt in {1..100} ; do cat basefile >> 100Xfile ; done` ? untested. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and concatenate the contents of the file to a temporary file.

```
COUNT=10 # larger or smaller, depending on how large you want the file
FILENAME=test.txt
# remove the mv command if you do not wish the original file to be overwritten
for i in $(seq 1 $COUNT) ; do cat $FILENAME >> $FILENAME.tmp ; done && mv $FILENAME.tmp $FILENAME
```

Comment: Works like a charm! ta! Have to wait 4 minutes to accept. You were too fast!